# Error when setup mantis

Tags: automated-testing, php, mantis

I have install  xampp server in my pc. and i have download mantis and trying to configuration mantis in my pc. i have sollw below step:

1)download mantis
2)paste mantis downloaded folder into the E:\XAMPP\htdocs\mantis-1.3.4
3)try to open xampp in browser like http://localhost:81/dashboard/ .it will open
4)i have change http://localhost:81/mantis-1.3.4/

but it display error
[image]